# Is this strange "return map" analytic?

Tags: analysis

Let $\gamma: \mathbb{R}\times (-\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_0)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be  a real analytic funtion, satisfying $\gamma( 0 , \varepsilon) = (0,0)$ for all $\varepsilon$ $\in$ $(\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_0)$, moreover $\forall$ $\varepsilon$, $\exists$ $t_\varepsilon>0$, such that $\gamma(t_\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$.

Define $\bar{t}_\varepsilon$ $=$ $\inf\{t;$ $\gamma(t,\varepsilon)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ and $t>0$ $\}$ and suppose the vectors $\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial t}(\bar{t}_\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and $(1,0)$ are linearly independent for all $\varepsilon$ $\in$ $(\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_0)$.

Now I'm wondering to know if the function $G: (-\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_0)\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$, $G(\varepsilon)= \gamma(\bar{t}_\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ is also an analytic funtion.

Can anyone help or give me a hint?

Comment: Consider $\gamma(t,\varepsilon) = (\varepsilon t , \sin(\varepsilon t^2 \pi))$. For any $\varepsilon$, $$\bar{t}_\varepsilon = \sqrt{\frac{1}{|\varepsilon|}},$$
then $$ G(\varepsilon) = \left(\varepsilon\sqrt{\frac{1}{|\varepsilon|}},0\right).$$

Comment: for $\varepsilon = 0$,$\bar{t}_\varepsilon = 0$ and $\frac{d\gamma}{dt} (0,0) =0$, which is not l.i with $(1,0)$.